¿como puedo incluir variables desde php usando la plataforma de WhatsApp Business de facebook developers?
la cuestion es que recibo variables des un formulario en php, la idea final es que se pueda enviar un mensaje de whatsapp donde muestre un mensaje   de bienvenida incluyendo los datos del usuario, el problema es que no  se como incluir las variables desde php  a la plantilla  hcha en la  plataforma de WhatsApp Business desde facebook: soy nueva en esto, asi que he buscado informacion, pero no logro tener exito,  aqui les dejo el codigo que estoy usando:
<?php
$variable1 = 'mi variable';
//TOKEN QUE NOS DA FACEBOOK
$token = 'EAAK8MB7NNGMBOZCoEARhFJ2uhyZB41FNON0oBPLWkB5Lon4LPIgCVPsJo1kWNFLGQzcZBFAZCV11fEDNN1K6I2fg1XF7yUiFO5kgrFnLrSvokdgEEHfLHpjLF2BlMXl59eIHvhxmnznuQim9QKpjZAQVqZA7RaHd9eY0lS3xvG19h3fqNdsr9XtOg8N2vqb7SwahTJiGqZAnCHaPXzz1KYZD';
//NUESTRO TELEFONO
$telefono = 'mi numero de telefono';
//URL A DONDE SE MANDARA EL MENSAJE
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/230672810135762/messages';

//CONFIGURACION DEL MENSAJE
$mensaje = ''
        . '{'
        . '"messaging_product": "whatsapp", '
        . '"to": "'.$telefono.'", '
        . '"type": "template", '
        . '"template": '
        . '{'
        . '     "name": "hello_world",'
        . '     "language":{ "code": "en_US" } '
        . '} '
        . '}';
//DECLARAMOS LAS CABECERAS
$header = array("Authorization: Bearer " . $token, "Content-Type: application/json",);
//INICIAMOS EL CURL
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $mensaje);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//OBTENEMOS LA RESPUESTA DEL ENVIO DE INFORMACION
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
//IMPRIMIMOS LA RESPUESTA 
print_r($response);
//OBTENEMOS EL CODIGO DE LA RESPUESTA
$status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//CERRAMOS EL CURL
curl_close($curl);

?>


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No entiendo tu problema.. no logras meter que variables??? porque por ejemplo, ahi metes el telefono...

Dime porfavor que ese $token lo has modificado y no es el real :) Si lo es, anúlalo de inmediato y genera uno nuevo. Nunca se deben publicar ese tipo de datos en ningún lado!

el token es de hace 2 dias, ya vencio

si funciona el token, acabo de probarlo

claro, por razones obvias no publico mi telefono ahi, pero en esa variable va mi telefono

claro, funciona para enviar unmensaje con una plantilla predefinida en la api whatsaap, pero no se como implementar las variables
